# get instance type from AWS managed batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

I'm using a step function to launch a batch job, how do I get the instance type that was ultimately used to process my job in a compute environment that is AWS managed? It doesn't look like this information is available with the CLI command [describe-jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/batch/describe-jobs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get at it through multiple CLI calls starting from the job-queue the job was submitted to; I'm using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter the results down for this example.

NOTE: this assumes the EC2 instance is still up when each of the commands listed below is called.

Get the compute environment used:

```
aws batch describe-job-queues --job-queues YOUR_JOB_QUEUE | jq '.jobQueues | .[0] | .computeEnvironmentOrder | .[0] | .computeEnvironment'
```

Get the ECS cluster ARN used:

```
aws batch describe-compute-environments --compute-environment FROM_PREVIOUS | jq '.computeEnvironments | .[0] | .ecsClusterArn'
```

Get the ECS container instance

```
aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster FROM_PREVIOUS | jq '.containerInstanceArns | .[0]'
```

Get the instance data

```
aws ecs describe-container-instances --container-instances FROM_PREVIOUS1 --cluster FROM_PREVIOUS2 | jq '.containerInstances | .[0] | .attributes | .[] | select(.name=="ecs.instance-type") | .value'
```